# Native Java API for Checking Valid XML

Tags: java, xml

How do you determine whether a `Document` object in Java contains valid XML. Is this checked when the object is constructed?

I can't appear to find any information on this in

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html
```

How do you determine whether you have a valid XML `Document` without using external libraries?

Note: I received this Document object by parsing from an input stream with a DOM XML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Java DOM API. It can handle any valid XML document. A valid document will give no exception. You need no external libraries for DOM.

In case of an error the exception message looks like this:

```
[Fatal Error] MyXMLFile.xml:6:2: The end-tag for element type "lastname" must end with a '>' delimiter.
The end-tag for element type "lastname" must end with a '>' delimiter.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```